# error "Property visual does not exist on type 'typeof barchart'" while creating power BI custom visual

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I'm trying to create a bar chart visual for power BI based on the microsoft tutorial on github. I have followed their environment setup steps exactly and was trying to create the visual with static data which is the first step.
But when I give the "pbiviz start" command,it results in an error : 
TYPESCRIPT/visualplugin.ts : (8,151) error Property visual does not exist on type 'typeof barchart'

I'm new to typescript and d3. Can someone Help?

Comment: Please provide the [relevant code to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is a environment setup required.
setup and coding done as per tutorial: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have changed the name of class `Visual` to `BarChart` You need to change the value of `"visualClassName"` property to your class name which in your case is `BarChart` in `pbiviz.json` file.
See the link :
http://www.dutchdatadude.com/power-bi-custom-visual-development-tip-visualplugin-ts-property-visual-does-not-exist-error/

Also you will have to change the file name in `"files"` property array in `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an API version conflict for `pbiviz`.

Note that the Github repo you referred is using v1.5.0, you need to specify version number when running `pbiviz update`:

```
#Update your version of pbiviz
npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools

#Run update from the root of your visual project (where pbiviz.json is located)
pbiviz update 1.5.0
```

Read more at: [Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/tools/usage.md#upgrading-to-a-different-api-version)

---

**UPDATE:**

I think I've spotted the bug from the hint: `typeof barchart`.

JavaScript identifiers are [case-sensitive](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp). So make sure you're following the cases used in the Github repo, e.g. `BarChart`, not `barchart`. (Or whatever it is)

Comment: I did what you suggested,but the same error occured.

Comment: @VishnuSuresh Can you add the exact steps you've done so that we can reproduce the error? Because I can't reproduce it based on the info you've provided.

Comment: First I did the necessary environment setup,installed the powerBi  CLI,installed the certificates,enabled the  developer tools,installed external libraries.
I am trying to do the First step,that is building the bar chart with static data.

Comment: @VishnuSuresh I think I've spotted the reason. Please check the above update to see if it's the `case` (No pun intended :))

Comment: The problem is with the guid of the visual found in pbiviz.json. it's a unique identifier for the visual. the error can be generalised as :
Property 'Visual' does not exist on type 'typeof guid'

Comment: @VishnuSuresh Did you find the solution for this issue?